# React Native Expo Can't save pdf via Share after assembly and filling in TestFlight

Tags: ios, reactjs, pdf, expo, native

I was updating my iOS app and ran into a problem - everything works through Expo GO (the pdf generation function printToFileAsync of the expo-print package and downloading via Share from react-native) But after creating the build and filling in TestFlight, the function stops working (the Sharing window just doesn't open) By itself, Sharing works if you remove the uri poured into it, but as soon as I pass either the url or the base64 link there, it stops working on the build (

If you pass base64 directly to the Share url, it doesn't work either

```js
let generatePdf = async() => {
  const file = await printToFileAsync({
    html: `
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </body>
    </html>
          `,
    base64: true
  });

  let shareOptionsUrl = {
    url: `data:application/pdf;base64,${file.base64}`
  };

  await Share.share(shareOptionsUrl);

};
```

Pdf creation and saving function in my iOS app
Thanks in advance for your help :3

I tried to pass an empty Share with only one message - it works in the build

If you pass the base64 code directly to the share url, it does not work in the build, it will work in expo go

If you pass the uri after pdf generation , it does not work in the build , in expo go it works